# Tree Data Structure with JPA and H2 Databse

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2

I have an entity class representing a tree data structure.

When using [H2 Database Engine](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) v1.4.200, I can persist entities without a problem.

However, when migrating to [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)'s latest version (v2.1.214), it throws an exception because of a `primary key` violation. It seems that is persisting the `parent` and the `root` with the entity (see exception below).

Any idea what could have changed in [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) from v1.4.200 to v2.1.214 that may be affecting the entity's persistence?

***Node.java***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class Node {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Node parent;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "root_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Node root;

    @Transient
    public List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

***NodeController.java***

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/node")
public class NodeController {

    private NodeService nodeService;

    public NodeController(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Node node) {
        Node entity = nodeService.save(node);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

***Exception***

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:
    Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.NODE(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'Node 1', NULL, NULL)"; SQL statement:
    insert into node (id, name, parent_id, root_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?) [23505-214]

.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:
    Resolved [org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.NODE(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'Node 1', NULL, NULL)"; SQL statement:<EOL>insert into node (id, name, parent_id, root_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?) [23505-214]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

Comment: Based on your entity's annotations, JPA should not be cascading persist (or any other) operations from the entity to its related parent or root entities.  I see no reason to suppose that changing the database would affect that, exceptions notwithstanding.

Comment: The code presented is not enough to diagnose the issue, but my guess would be that it is attributable to some other change that went live at or about the same time as the DB upgrade.

Comment: @John Bollinger Thanks for your comment. I don't think there is some other change. It's an In-Memory database that is created before each test. And I have done tests moving from one version to the other and back, and the exception is triggered only on the latest version.

Comment: It looks like a row with explicitly specified value of `id` column was inserted earlier. It isn't possible to mix insertions with custom `id` values and auto-generated `id` values into identity columns that easy, modern versions of H2 are standard-compliant by default in that area and don't change base value of identity column generator after insertion of explicitly specified values.

Comment: @Evgenij Ryazanov You are right! That was the issue. Please add your comment as an answer, and I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity columns have a generator that produces values for each new row. If an identity column was declared as generated by default, it is possible to specify an own value for it, in this case generator isn't used. If the specified value is from the range of generated values it may conflict with values produced by this generator. For example,

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST(
    ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    VAL INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, VAL) VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, VAL) VALUES (DEFAULT, 20); // <- generator also returns 1
```

To avoid this, you should avoid insertion of custom values into these columns, always specify `DEFAULT` or don't include these columns into lists of columns in `INSERT` commands. If this is not an option, you need to adjust generator by yourself after such insertions:

```sql
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, VAL) VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO TEST(ID, VAL) VALUES (2, 11);
// ...
ALTER TABLE TEST ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TEST) + 1;
```

You can also specify a custom interval for identity column (with `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1000)`, for example) and use values outside of this interval for insertions with custom values.

---

This issue doesn't appear with historic unsupported version of H2 database, because they incorrectly perform automatic adjustment of generator after insertions of custom values, this behavior was copied from auto-increment columns from MySQL.

H2 2.*.* implements identity columns from the SQL Standard and doesn't adjust their generators by itself (excluding some compatibility modes where such adjustment is performed for compatibility with other database systems).

Automatic adjustment is actually insecure, because a user with limited access  permissions can exhaust generator of identity column with only one insertion of special value and break following insertions with generated values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my specific case, I didn't remove the tag `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` from the `id` column. Also, I didn't have to add a generator. Finally, I didn't have to insert the entity with the `id`. Using your example, `INSERT INTO TEST(VAL) VALUES (110)` did the trick.